# How to convert phone numbers into given format?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I want to create a scalar function which would format a phone number in the way as follows:
I have:

```
Phone
----------  
606548795, 112556884  
777090811
606721568
```

I want:

```
Phone
> --------
> +420 606 548 795, +420 112 556 884
> +420 777 090 811
> +420 606 721 568
```

I tried:

```
SELECT @String FROM STRING_SPLIT(@String, ',')

    IF(@CountryID = 1)
       BEGIN
          IF(SUBSTRING(@String,1,9) LIKE '%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%')
             RETURN CONCAT(@CountryCode, ' ', SUBSTRING(@String,1,3), ' ', SUBSTRING(@String,4,3), ' ', SUBSTRING(@String,7,3))
          ELSE
             RETURN ''
       END
```

-- Works for one (first) phone number withou that String_Split :-)

I already have body of the function, just need a help with the construction.
Any hints would be aprreciated.

Comment: How many numbers can be stored in a single row? Is there any limit?

Comment: Max. 2 numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FORMAT SQL Server (starting with 2012)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql

```
SELECT FORMAT(606548795,'+420 000 000 000')
```

Comment: `FORMAT()` not supported by `NVARCHAR, CHAR, VARCHAR`

Answer (score 0):

If you have always one numbers per row then you could use of `stuff()` function & add single space after each three digits gap

```
SELECT STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(concat('+420', @phone), 5, 0, SPACE(1)), 9, 0, SPACE(1)), 13, 0, SPACE(1));
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which version of SQL Server you're using, but this should work in just about all of them (assuming that the actual format of the numbers doesn't change):

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE 
(
    PhoneNos    VARCHAR(255)
)
;

INSERT INTO @TABLE 
SELECT '606548795, 112556884'
    UNION ALL
SELECT '777090811'
    UNION ALL 
SELECT '606721568'
;

SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN CHARINDEX(',',PhoneNos) > 1
            THEN 
                '+420 ' + STUFF(STUFF(LEFT(PhoneNos,9),4,0,' '),8,0,' ')
                + ', ' +
                '+420' + STUFF(STUFF(RIGHT(PhoneNos,CHARINDEX(',',REVERSE(PhoneNos)) - 1),5,0,' '),9,0,' ')
        ELSE
            '+420 ' + STUFF(STUFF(PhoneNos,4,0,' '),8,0,' ')
    END
FROM @TABLE T
;
```

Returns:

```
+420 606 548 795, +420 112 556 884
+420 777 090 811
+420 606 721 568
```

This depends on the fact that you only ever have a maximum of two phone numbers listed in the column, separated by a comma. If you have more, then it will need to be reworked.

Also, I just want to mention that storing multiple values in a single column is a bit of a no-no, precisely because of things like this.

You could use a separate function to divide comma-separated values into single entries in a temporary table, and then run your single-valued function on those entries to get a better, more stable result.

If that interests you, let me know and I can work one out for you.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, according to your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47468800/how-to-convert-phone-numbers-into-given-format/47469077#comment81892188_47468800):

```
CREATE TABLE PhoneNumber (
    Phone VARCHAR(MAX)
    );

INSERT INTO PhoneNumber VALUES
('606548795, 112556884'),  
('777090811'),
('606721568');

SELECT Phone, CASE WHEN LEN(Phone) > 9 THEN '+420 ' + LEFT(Phone, 9) + ' , +420 ' + RIGHT(Phone, 9)
              ELSE '+420 '+ LEFT(Phone, 9) END AS Result
FROM PhoneNumber;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is based on that you will have max. 2 numbers in one row:

```
declare @x table(COLUMN_NAME varchar(30))
insert into @x values
('606548795, 112556884'),  
('777090811'),
('606721568');
declare @prefix varchar(5)
set @prefix = '+420 '

SELECT case when CHARINDEX(',', COLUMN_NAME) = 0 then @prefix + FORMAT(convert(int,COLUMN_NAME), '000 000 000')
            else @prefix + format(convert(int,substring(COLUMN_NAME, 1, charindex(',',COLUMN_NAME) - 1)),'000 000 000') + ', ' + @prefix +
                 format(convert(int,substring(COLUMN_NAME, charindex(',',COLUMN_NAME) + 2, LEN(COLUMN_NAME))),'000 000 000')
       end
FROM @x
```